# I wrote a taghelper class and then i add it to my _viewImport . but it isn't known in my layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, class, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I wrote this tagHelper class

```
//[HtmlTargetElement("MenuItem")]
 public class MenuItemTagHelper : TagHelper
 {
     private readonly IGetMenuItemService getMenuItemService;
     public MenuItemTagHelper(IGetMenuItemService getMenuItemService)
     {
         this.getMenuItemService = getMenuItemService;
     }
     public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
     {
         output.TagName = "ul";
         output.Content.AppendHtml(GetContent());
     }
     private TagBuilder GetContent()
     {
         var data = getMenuItemService.Execute();
         TagBuilder liMain = null;
         foreach (var item in data.Where(p => p.ParentId == null))
         {
             if (liMain == null)
             {
                 liMain = CreateLi(item.Name, "");
             }
             else
             {
                 liMain.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(CreateLi(item.Name, ""));
             }
             var ul = new TagBuilder("ul");
             ul.AddCssClass("row");
             var liAll = CreateLi($"همه دسته بندی های  {item.Name}", "#");
             liAll.AddCssClass("col-12");
             ul.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(liAll);

             TagBuilder liCol_1 = CreateLi();
             liCol_1.AddCssClass("col-3");
             TagBuilder liCol_2 = CreateLi();
             liCol_2.AddCssClass("col-3");
             TagBuilder liCol_3 = CreateLi();
             liCol_3.AddCssClass("col-3");
             TagBuilder liCol_4 = CreateLi();
             liCol_4.AddCssClass("col-3");

             int index = 0;
             foreach (var sub1 in data.Where(p => p.ParentId == item.Id))
             {
                 if (index < 13)
                 {
                     var a = new TagBuilder("a");
                     a.MergeAttribute("href", $"#");
                     a.InnerHtml.Append(sub1.Name);
                     liCol_1.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(a);

                     liCol_1.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(CreateSub(data, sub1, index, out index));
                     index++;
                 }
                 else if (index < 26)
                 {
                     var a = new TagBuilder("a");
                     a.MergeAttribute("href", $"#");
                     a.InnerHtml.Append(sub1.Name);
                     liCol_2.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(a);

                     liCol_2.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(CreateSub(data, sub1, index, out index));
                     index++;
                 }
                 else if (index < 39)
                 {
                     var a = new TagBuilder("a");
                     a.MergeAttribute("href", $"#");
                     a.InnerHtml.Append(sub1.Name);
                     liCol_3.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(a);

                     liCol_3.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(CreateSub(data, sub1, index, out index));
                     index++;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     var a = new TagBuilder("a");
                     a.MergeAttribute("href", $"#");
                     a.InnerHtml.Append(sub1.Name);
                     liCol_4.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(a);

                     liCol_4.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(CreateSub(data, sub1, index, out index));
                     index++;
                 }
             }
             ul.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(liCol_1);
             ul.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(liCol_2);
             ul.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(liCol_3);
             ul.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(liCol_4);
             liMain.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(ul);
         }
         return liMain;
     }

     private TagBuilder CreateSub(List<MenuItemDto> data, MenuItemDto sub1, int count, out int IndexCount)
     {
         IndexCount = count;
         var ulsub2 = new TagBuilder("ul");
         foreach (var sub2 in data.Where(p => p.ParentId == sub1.Id))
         {
             ulsub2.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(CreateLi(sub2.Name, "#"));
             IndexCount++;
         }
         return ulsub2;
     }

     private TagBuilder CreateLi(string Text, string Link)
     {
         var a = new TagBuilder("a");
         a.MergeAttribute("href", $"{Link}");
         a.MergeAttribute("title", Text);
         a.InnerHtml.Append(Text);
         var li = new TagBuilder("li");

         li.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(a);
         return li;
     }
     private TagBuilder CreateLi()
     {
         var li = new TagBuilder("li");
         return li;
     }
 }
```

And then I add this to my `_viewImports.chtml`
(my project name is Store)

```
@using Store
@using Store.Models

@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, Store
```

but my layout can't recognize my `tagHelper`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HJMD.png)

Comment: Please follow my simple code sample to check if it runs well. https://codeshare.io/AdkL0p What’s your .net version and check if namespace of your TagHelper is correct. Any problems please let me know.